# R Date Format in Spotfire

Tags: r, spotfire

I have a column in a dataframe: 16542.00.  I am trying to convert it to 04/17/2015.

I have tried:

```
df<-mutate(.data = df, DateColumn= as.Date(DateColumn, "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

I get this error:

> Changing datatype of an existing property is not allowed. Old datatype: Date, new datatype: Real

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
df<-data.frame(DateColumn=as.numeric(16542:16545))
 df%>%
   mutate(DateColumn=format(as.Date(DateColumn, origin = "1970-01-01"), format="%m/%d/%Y"))
  DateColumn
1 04/17/2015
2 04/18/2015
3 04/19/2015
4 04/20/2015
```